# How do I sort a table by the maximum value of associated records?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a client model which has many meetings.

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :meetings

end

class Meeting < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client

end
```

I want to produce an ActiveRecord query that will return clients sorted by order of the most recent meeting (as determined by the meeting_time column), but have no idea how to do this. I obviously need to join the tables somehow but I don't know how to generate a suitable subquery in AR. How do I write a join that only includes 1 meeting for each client, in particular the most recent meeting (i.e. the highest value for meetings.meeting_time for a given meetings.client_id). My database is PostgreSQL.

I've encountered similar problems to this previously, struggled with them, and obviously haven't learned a lot from the process. A pointer to a good resource to learn about these sort of situations would also be appreciated.

Comment: what does recent mean? last week? last month?

Comment: It doesn't matter. I'm looking for the most recent.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Client.joins(:meetings).group('clients.id').order('max(meetings.meeting_time) DESC')
```

This will:

1. Grab clients
2. Join them with meetings
3. Group by the client (id)
4. Now we can use `max(meetings.meeting_time)` which is the most recent meeting for each client
5. Then sort clients by the most recent meeting time in descending order

Comment: That gives the error PG::Error: ERROR:  column "meetings.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function with PostgreSQL, but changing the group clause to .group('clients.id, meetings.id') gives me exactly what I want. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, on closer inspection that will return multiple instances of Client if there is more than 1 meeting. Doh! Any further advances?

Comment: Yes, if you group by client id and meetings id you end up with one row per client and meeting which is not what we want. I've tested the query and it's working fine for me, what is the sql query that is being executed for you? Do you have any scope in your models?

Comment: Sorry for delay. The error I get is as per my comment above. There is no scope in my models. Which db did you test with? I'm told Postgres is stricter than others.

Comment: Hmm, actually on reattempting this it seems to work just fine. I wonder what changed? Anyway, sorry to be difficult.

Comment: This is going to be deprecated in Rails 6+. ```DEPRECATION WARNING: Dangerous query method (method whose arguments are used as raw SQL) called with non-attribute argument(s)```